# Adobe Flex Android Mobile - Preventing inactivity causing loss of control values?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex-spark

I am working on a mobile application that does a simple age calcualation.  I have a datespinner that update 3 labels. When I first start my mobile app on my android device it works great. I am able to update the controls multiple times with out any issue.

The problem I am encountering is that when the app becomes inactive for few hours and then I return to the app it loses it's values.  The weird thing is that I try to change the date spinner and the labels do not get updated and the date spinner returns to the default date. Is there an event that I need to hook into to correct this issue? Could someone help explain what is happening?  I checked Adobe's support site and they do not offer anything on this issue.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your app, while inactive, is killed by the Android system to prioritize the system's resources. When you return to your app it is relaunched, but your app's state is lost and returns to default. To avoid losing the app's state, you need to save the variables that determine the state - in your case the spinner's position - in persistent memory. One way to preserve state is to use the [PersistenceManager](http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/11/01/flex-4-5-persistencemanager/). [Here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Simple_data_persistence_in_a_Flex_4_5_mobile_appli-18856.html) is an example on how to use it.

You need to decide *when* to save the state. There are useful events you can listen to at app level such as

```
Event.DEACTIVATE
```

to trigger the write to persistent memory.